# Sprite Kit game crashing after changing scene back to original scene

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, ios7.1

I have a game that works great and is in the app store. I am making an update in which I added another scene. When the game starts up it will still work fine, but if I change to the other scene and then go back to the first scene, the game still works fine. However, if I play the game once and then press the button to go to the other scene and then go back to the first scene, the game crashes when I try to play it with the error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Attemped to add a SKNode which already has a parent: <SKNode> name:'(null)' position:{0, 0} accumulatedFrame:{{inf, inf}, {inf, inf}}'
```

I tried removing all children from the scene before the transition, but I still get the error.

Code to change scenes:

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Settings Button"]) {
        MySettingsScene *settingsScene = [MySettingsScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
        [self.view presentScene:settingsScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionLeft duration:.5]];
    }
```

Code to change back:

```
if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"Back Button"]) {
    MyScene *homeScene = [MyScene sceneWithSize:self.size];
    [self.view presentScene:homeScene transition:[SKTransition pushWithDirection:SKTransitionDirectionRight duration:.5]];
}
```

Line causing it to crash

[image]

Comment: Which line is causing the crash? Have you set an exception breakpoint to find the code that is crashing?

Comment: Oh right, sorry, I forgot that line, I'll add it now

Comment: This is not the line causing the crash. This is just telling you that the app has crashed. You need to add an exception breakpoint. This will stop on a line of your own code.

Comment: Learn to use the debugger. You have a huge hint in that it's telling you that you are trying to add a `SKNode` that already has a parent.  So drop a breakpoint wherever you handle the button tap and step through till it crashes.

Comment: Thanks for that. I used the debugger and found that when I'm going back to the other scene, it's not starting the scene over, it's continuing from where it left off. But the scene still gets initialized, so it looks like it started over. So it's calling the same method twice in two different places... How would I go about making the scene completely reinitialize?

Comment: Alright I solved my problem, but I still don't know why it was happening. When I transition back to the new scene, none of my variables were getting initialized the way they do when the game first opens. So for example I have a boolean value called gameIsOver, and it starts out false, and when the user gets a game over, it changes to true. Then I go to the next scene and go back and everything appeared to have started over, but gameIsOver was still true. Any idea why it doesn't reset?

Answer (score 0):

If you actually read the log error it says you're attempting to add a child twice somewhere in your code. Thus causing it to crash. Run through your code and double check that.

Comment: I know that's what's causing the error, it's just that the node that's being added has no value, everything is nil. So I don't know what's being added that's causing it to crash, when it works fine before changing scenes. Also, it still crashes if I remove all children before the point where it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are looking to dismiss your current scene and move to a new scene. To do that you can `[mySKView presentScene:nil];` and then move onto your new scene.